# Segment user input for location based search?

Tags: regex, search, full-text-search, location

I'm implementing a location based search on my website that asks an open-ended question of `location?` with a textfield for user input.

A user can input any combination of things such as city, state, zip, just city, just state, just zip or even a full address such as `123 elm st Dallas, TX 75206`

The biggest challenge comes in user input variance. For exampl some cities have a space or hifen in their name such as `San Diego`.

Some people input addresses differently. `Dallas, TX 75206` or `Dallas TX 75206` or `Dallas, TX, 75206` or `Dallas, TX`. There is a plethora of ways to input addresses.

I guess what I was wondering is if there is a common regular expression, method or formula used to break up these parts and match them to their correct peices. I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel and thise seems like it could be common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I basically broke each piece down and used logic to try and segment what most users could/should be using as parameters.

(This is using CakePHP)

```
<?php
    $addrString = $this->request->query['location'];
    //converto the address string to uppercase to match against the city and state arrays
    $addrString = strtoupper($addrString);

    //Convert address to array to look for a zip code
    $addrArray = preg_split('/[;,. \n]+/', $addrString);

    //List of cities in Oregon and Washington
    $cities = array('ABERDEEN','ABERDEEN GARDENS','ACME','AHTANUM','AIRWAY HEIGHTS','ALBION','ALDERWOOD MANOR','ALGER','ALGONA','ALLYN-GRAPEVIEW','ALMIRA','AMBOY','AMES LAKE','ANACORTES','ARLINGTON','ARLINGTON HEIGHTS','ARTONDALE','ASHFORD','ASOTIN','AUBURN','AULT FIELD','BAINBRIDGE ISLAND','BANGOR TRIDENT BASE','BANKS LAKE SOUTH','BARBERTON','BARING','BASIN CITY','BATTLE GROUND','BAY CENTER','BAY VIEW','BEAUX ARTS VILLAGE','BELLEVUE','BELL HILL','BELLINGHAM','BENTON CITY','BICKLETON','BIG LAKE','BINGEN','BIRCH BAY','BLACK DIAMOND','BLAINE','BLYN','BONNEY LAKE','BOTHELL','BRADY','BREMERTON','BREWSTER','BRIDGEPORT','BRIER','BRINNON','BRUSH PRAIRIE','BRYN MAWR-SKYWAY','BUCKLEY','BUCODA','BURBANK','BURIEN','BURLINGTON','CAMANO','CAMAS','CARBONADO','CARLSBORG','CARNATION','CARSON RIVER VALLEY','CASCADE-FAIRWOOD','CASCADE VALLEY','CASHMERE','CASTLE ROCK','CATHAN','CATHCART','CATHLAMET','CENTERVILLE','CENTRALIA','CENTRAL PARK','CHEHALIS','CHEHALIS VILLAGE','CHELAN','CHENEY','CHERRY GROVE','CHEWELAH','CHINOOK','CLARKSTON','CLARKSTON HEIGHTS-VINELAND','CLEAR LAKE','CLE ELUM','CLINTON','CLYDE HILL','COHASSETT BEACH','COLFAX','COLLEGE PLACE','COLTON','COLVILLE','CONCONULLY','CONCRETE','CONNELL','CONWAY','COPALIS BEACH','COSMOPOLIS','COTTAGE LAKE','COULEE CITY','COULEE DAM','COUNTRY HOMES','COUPEVILLE','COVINGTON','CRESTON','CUSICK','CUSTER','DALLESPORT','DARRINGTON','DAVENPORT','DAYTON','DEER PARK','DEMING','DESERT AIRE','DES MOINES','DISHMAN','DIXIE','DOLLAR CORNER','DUPONT','DUVALL','EAST CATHLAMET','EASTGATE','EAST HILL-MERIDIAN','EASTON','EAST PORT ORCHARD','EAST RENTON HIGHLANDS','EAST WENATCHEE','EAST WENATCHEE BENCH','EATONVILLE','ECHO LAKE','EDGEWOOD','EDISON','EDMONDS','ELBE','ELECTRIC CITY','ELK PLAIN','ELLENSBURG','ELMA','ELMER CITY','ENDICOTT','ENTIAT','ENUMCLAW','EPHRATA','ERLANDS POINT-KITSAP LAKE','ESCHBACH','ESPERANCE','EVERETT','EVERSON','FAIRCHILD AFB','FAIRFIELD','FAIRWOOD','FALL CITY','FARMINGTON','FEDERAL WAY','FELIDA','FERNDALE','FIFE','FINLEY','FIRCREST','FIVE CORNERS','FORDS PRAIRIE','FORKS','FORT LEWIS','FOX ISLAND','FREDERICKSON','FREELAND','FRIDAY HARBOR','GARFIELD','GARRETT','GENEVA','GEORGE','GIG HARBOR','GLACIER','GLEED','GOLD BAR','GOLDENDALE','GRAHAM','GRAND COULEE','GRAND MOUND','GRANDVIEW','GRANGER','GRANITE FALLS','GRAYLAND','GREEN ACRES','GREENWATER','HAMILTON','HARRAH','HARRINGTON','HARTLINE','HATTON','HAZEL DELL NORTH','HAZEL DELL SOUTH','HIGHLAND','HOBART','HOCKINSON','HOQUIAM','HUMPTULIPS','HUNTS POINT','ILWACO','INCHELIUM','INDEX','INDIANOLA','INGLEWOOD-FINN HILL','IONE','ISSAQUAH','JOHN SAM LAKE','JORDAN ROAD-CANYON CREEK','JUNCTION CITY','KAHLOTUS','KALAMA','KELSO','KENDALL','KENMORE','KENNEWICK','KENT','KETTLE FALLS','KINGSGATE','KINGSTON','KIRKLAND','KITTITAS','KLICKITAT','KRUPP','LA CENTER','LACEY','LA CONNER','LA CROSSE','LAKE BOSWORTH','LAKE CAVANAUGH','LAKE FOREST PARK','LAKE GOODWIN','LAKE KETCHUM','LAKELAND NORTH','LAKELAND SOUTH','LAKE MCMURRAY','LAKE MARCEL-STILLWATER','LAKE MORTON-BERRYDALE','LAKE ROESIGER','LAKE SHORE','LAKE STEVENS','LAKEVIEW','LAKEWOOD','LAMONT','LANGLEY','LATAH','LEA HILL','LEAVENWORTH','LEBAM','LEWISVILLE','LIBERTY LAKE','LIND','LOCHSLOY','LONG BEACH','LONGVIEW','LONGVIEW HEIGHTS','LYLE','LYMAN','LYNDEN','LYNNWOOD','MABTON','MCCHORD AFB','MCCLEARY','MACHIAS','MALDEN','MALONE-PORTER','MALTBY','MANCHESTER','MANSFIELD','MAPLE FALLS','MAPLE HEIGHTS-LAKE DESIRE','MAPLE VALLEY','MARBLEMOUNT','MARCUS','MARIETTA-ALDERWOOD','MARKHAM','MARROWSTONE','MARTHA LAKE','MARYHILL','MARYSVILLE','MATTAWA','MAY CREEK','MEADOW GLADE','MEDICAL LAKE','MEDINA','MERCER ISLAND','MESA','METALINE','METALINE FALLS','MIDLAND','MILL CREEK','MILL PLAIN','MILLWOOD','MILTON','MINNEHAHA','MIRRORMONT','MOCLIPS','MONROE','MONTESANO','MORTON','MOSES LAKE','MOSES LAKE NORTH','MOSSYROCK','MOUNTLAKE TERRACE','MOUNT VERNON','MOUNT VISTA','MOXEE','MUKILTEO','NACHES','NAPAVINE','NASELLE','NAVY YARD CITY','NEAH BAY','NEILTON','NESPELEM','NESPELEM COMMUNITY','NEWCASTLE','NEWPORT','NISQUALLY INDIAN COMMUNITY','NOOKSACK','NORMANDY PARK','NORTH BEND','NORTH BONNEVILLE','NORTH CREEK','NORTH MARYSVILLE','NORTH OMAK','NORTHPORT','NORTH STANWOOD','NORTH SULTAN','NORTHWEST SNOHOMISH','NORTH YELM','OAKESDALE','OAK HARBOR','OAKVILLE','OCEAN CITY','OCEAN PARK','OCEAN SHORES','ODESSA','OKANOGAN','OLYMPIA','OMAK','OPPORTUNITY','ORCHARDS','OROVILLE','ORTING','OSO','OTHELLO','OTIS ORCHARDS-EAST FARMS','OYEHUT-HOGANS CORNER','PACIFIC','PAINE FIELD-LAKE STICKNEY','PALOUSE','PARKLAND','PARKWOOD','PASCO','PATEROS','PEACEFUL VALLEY','PE ELL','PICNIC POINT-NORTH LYNNWOOD','POMEROY','PORT ANGELES','PORT ANGELES EAST','PORT HADLOCK-IRONDALE','PORT LUDLOW','PORT ORCHARD','PORT TOWNSEND','POULSBO','PRAIRIE RIDGE','PRESCOTT','PRIEST POINT','PROSSER','PULLMAN','PUYALLUP','QUILCENE','QUINCY','RAINIER','RAVENSDALE','RAYMOND','REARDAN','REDMOND','RENTON','REPUBLIC','RICHLAND','RIDGEFIELD','RITZVILLE','RIVERBEND','RIVER ROAD','RIVERSIDE','RIVERTON-BOULEVARD PARK','ROCHESTER','ROCKFORD','ROCK ISLAND','ROCKPORT','RONALD','ROOSEVELT','ROSALIA','ROSLYN','ROY','ROYAL CITY','RUSTON','ST. JOHN','SALMON CREEK','SAMMAMISH','SATSOP','SATUS','SEATAC','SEATTLE','SEATTLE HILL-SILVER FIRS','SEDRO-WOOLLEY','SELAH','SEQUIM','SHAKER CHURCH','SHELTON','SHORELINE','SILVANA','SILVERDALE','SKOKOMISH','SKYKOMISH','SMOKEY POINT','SNOHOMISH','SNOQUALMIE','SNOQUALMIE PASS','SOAP LAKE','SOUTH BEND','SOUTH CLE ELUM','SOUTH HILL','SOUTH PRAIRIE','SOUTH WENATCHEE','SPANAWAY','SPANGLE','SPOKANE','SPRAGUE','SPRINGDALE','STANWOOD','STARBUCK','STARTUP','STEILACOOM','STEVENSON','STIMSON CROSSING','SUDDEN VALLEY','SULTAN','SUMAS','SUMMIT','SUMMITVIEW','SUMNER','SUNNYSIDE','SUNNYSLOPE','SUQUAMISH','TACOMA','TAHOLAH','TANGLEWILDE-THOMPSON PLACE','TANNER','TEKOA','TENINO','TERRACE HEIGHTS','THORP','THREE LAKES','TIETON','TOKELAND','TOLEDO','TONASKET','TOPPENISH','TOUCHET','TOWN AND COUNTRY','TRACYTON','TRENTWOOD','TROUT LAKE','TUKWILA','TULALIP BAY','TUMWATER','TWISP','UNION GAP','UNION HILL-NOVELTY HILL','UNIONTOWN','UNIVERSITY PLACE','VADER','VANCOUVER','VANTAGE','VASHON','VENERSBORG','VERADALE','VERLOT','WAITSBURG','WALLA WALLA','WALLA WALLA EAST','WALLER','WALLULA','WALNUT GROVE','WAPATO','WARDEN','WARM BEACH','WASHOUGAL','WASHTUCNA','WATERVILLE','WAVERLY','WEALLUP LAKE','WENATCHEE','WEST CLARKSTON-HIGHLAND','WEST LAKE SAMMAMISH','WEST LAKE STEVENS','WEST LONGVIEW','WEST PASCO','WESTPORT','WEST RICHLAND','WEST SIDE HIGHWAY','WEST VALLEY','WEST WENATCHEE','WHITE CENTER','WHITE SALMON','WHITE SWAN','WILBUR','WILKESON','WILSON CREEK','WINLOCK','WINTHROP','WISHRAM','WOODINVILLE','WOODLAND','WOODS CREEK','WOODWAY','YACOLT','YAKIMA','YARROW POINT','YELM','ZILLAH','ADAIR VILLAGE','ADAMS','ADRIAN','ALBANY','ALOHA','ALTAMONT','AMITY','ANTELOPE','ARLINGTON','ASHLAND','ASTORIA','ATHENA','AUMSVILLE','AURORA','BAKER CITY','BANDON','BANKS','BARLOW','BARVIEW','BAY CITY','BEAVER','BEAVERTON','BEND','BIGGS JUNCTION','BOARDMAN','BONANZA','BROOKINGS','BROOKS','BROWNSVILLE','BUNKER HILL','BURNS','BUTTE FALLS','BUTTEVILLE','CANBY','CANNON BEACH','CANYON CITY','CANYONVILLE','CAPE MEARES','CARLTON','CASCADE LOCKS','CAVE JUNCTION','CAYUSE','CEDAR HILLS','CEDAR MILL','CENTRAL POINT','CHENOWETH','CHILOQUIN','CITY OF THE DALLES','CLACKAMAS','CLATSKANIE','CLOVERDALE','COBURG','COLUMBIA CITY','CONDON','COOS BAY','COQUILLE','CORNELIUS','CORVALLIS','COTTAGE GROVE','COVE','CRESWELL','CULVER','DALLAS','DAYTON','DAYVILLE','DEPOE BAY','DESCHUTES RIVER WOODS','DETROIT','DONALD','DRAIN','DUFUR','DUNDEE','DUNES CITY','DURHAM','EAGLE POINT','ECHO','ELGIN','ELKTON','ENTERPRISE','EOLA','ESTACADA','EUGENE','FAIRVIEW','FALLS CITY','FLORENCE','FOREST GROVE','FOSSIL','FOUR CORNERS','GARDEN HOME-WHITFORD','GARIBALDI','GASTON','GATES','GEARHART','GERVAIS','GLADSTONE','GLENDALE','GLIDE','GOLD BEACH','GOLD HILL','GOPHER FLATS','GRAND RONDE','GRANITE','GRANTS PASS','GRASS VALLEY','GREEN','GREENHORN','GRESHAM','HAINES','HALFWAY','HALSEY','HAPPY VALLEY','HARBECK-FRUITDALE','HARBOR','HARRISBURG','HAYESVILLE','HEBO','HELIX','HEPPNER','HERMISTON','HILLSBORO','HINES','HOOD RIVER','HUBBARD','HUNTINGTON','IDANHA','IMBLER','INDEPENDENCE','IONE','IRRIGON','ISLAND CITY','JACKSONVILLE','JEFFERSON','JENNINGS LODGE','JOHN DAY','JOHNSON CITY','JORDAN VALLEY','JOSEPH','JUNCTION CITY','KEIZER','KING CITY','KIRKPATRICK','KLAMATH FALLS','LABISH VILLAGE','LAFAYETTE','LA GRANDE','LAKE OSWEGO','LAKESIDE','LAKEVIEW','LA PINE','LEBANON','LEXINGTON','LINCOLN BEACH','LINCOLN CITY','LONEROCK','LONG CREEK','LOSTINE','LOWELL','LYONS','MCMINNVILLE','MADRAS','MALIN','MANZANITA','MARION','MAUPIN','MAYWOOD PARK','MEDFORD','MEHAMA','MERRILL','METOLIUS','METZGER','MILL CITY','MILLERSBURG','MILTON-FREEWATER','MILWAUKIE','MISSION','MITCHELL','MOLALLA','MONMOUTH','MONROE','MONUMENT','MORO','MOSIER','MOUNT ANGEL','MOUNT HOOD VILLAGE','MOUNT VERNON','MYRTLE CREEK','MYRTLE POINT','NEHALEM','NESKOWIN','NETARTS','NEWBERG','NEWPORT','NORTH BEND','NORTH PLAINS','NORTH POWDER','NYSSA','OAK GROVE','OAK HILLS','OAKLAND','OAKRIDGE','OATFIELD','OCEANSIDE','ODELL','ONTARIO','OREGON CITY','PACIFIC CITY','PAISLEY','PARKDALE','PENDLETON','PHILOMATH','PHOENIX','PILOT ROCK','PINE GROVE','PINE HOLLOW','PORTLAND','PORT ORFORD','POWERS','PRAIRIE CITY','PRESCOTT','PRINEVILLE','RAINIER','RALEIGH HILLS','REDMOND','REDWOOD','REEDSPORT','RICHLAND','RICKREALL','RIDDLE','RIVERGROVE','RIVERSIDE','ROCKAWAY BEACH','ROCKCREEK','ROGUE RIVER','ROSEBURG','ROSEBURG NORTH','ROSE LODGE','ROWENA','RUFUS','ST. HELENS','ST. PAUL','SALEM','SANDY','SCAPPOOSE','SCIO','SCOTTS MILLS','SEASIDE','SENECA','SHADY COVE','SHANIKO','SHERIDAN','SHERWOOD','SILETZ','SILVERTON','SISTERS','SODAVILLE','SOUTH LEBANON','SPRAY','SPRINGFIELD','STANFIELD','STAYTON','SUBLIMITY','SUMMERVILLE','SUMPTER','SUNNYSIDE','SUTHERLIN','SWEET HOME','TALENT','TANGENT','TERREBONNE','THREE RIVERS','TIGARD','TILLAMOOK','TOLEDO','TRI-CITY','TROUTDALE','TUALATIN','TURNER','TUTUILLA','TYGH VALLEY','UKIAH','UMATILLA','UNION','UNITY','VALE','VENETA','VERNONIA','WALDPORT','WALLOWA','WAMIC','WARM SPRINGS','WARRENTON','WASCO','WATERLOO','WESTFIR','WEST HAVEN-SYLVAN','WEST LINN','WESTON','WEST SLOPE','WHEELER','WHITE CITY','WILLAMINA','WILSONVILLE','WINCHESTER BAY','WINSTON','WOODBURN','WOOD VILLAGE','YACHATS','YAMHILL','YONCALLA'); 
    //These cities appear both in Oregon and Washington
    $duplicateCities = array('ARLINGTON', 'BEAVER', 'BRIDGEPORT', 'CARLTON', 'COLTON', 'DAYTON', 'IONE', 'KENT');
    //Variations of State spellings/abbreviations
    $states = array('WA', 'WASH', 'WASHINGTON', 'OR', 'ORE', 'OREGON');

    //Grab last item in address array, take first 5 characters
    $possibleZip = end($addrArray);
    $possibleZip = substr($possibleZip, 0, 5);
    //See if it looks like it could be a zipcode
    if(preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $possibleZip)){
        //If the last part of the string looks like it could be a zip code
        //use that zip as the zip code to use for the search";  
        //$zip_to_search = $possibleZip;
        $conditions[] = array('Listing.ZipCode' => $possibleZip); 
    }else{
        //echo "Do a search of comparison of the addr_string array against the cities array to see if a city can be found and searched for. If not, return nothing?<br />";  
        //Check to see if the address string contains a city in WA or OR
        $city = $this->contains($addrString, $cities);
        $city = end($city);

        $state = array_intersect($addrArray, $states);
        $state = substr(end($state), 0, 2);

        if($city){
            if( in_array($city, $duplicateCities)){
            //Check to see if there's a duplicate city, 
            //If there is you'll have to do a search on both City and State
                if($state){
                    //$addr_conditions[] = array('Zip.state_prefix' => $state); 
                    //$addr_conditions[] = array('Zip.City' => $city); 
                    //$addr_state = $this->Zip->find('first', array('conditions' => $addr_conditions));
                    //$zip_to_search = $addr_state['Zip']['zip_code'];

                    $conditions[] = array('Listing.City' => $city); 
                    $conditions[] = array('Listing.State' => $state);
                }
            }else{
            //If no duplicate city was found above, just do a search on the city provided
                //$addr_city = $this->Zip->findByCity($city);
                //$zip_to_search = $addr_city['Zip']['zip_code'];
                $conditions[] = array('Listing.City' => $city); 
            }

        }elseif($state){
            //$addr_conditions[] = array('Zip.state_prefix' => $state); 
            //$addr_conditions[] = array('Zip.City' => $city); 
            //$addr_state = $this->Zip->find('first', array('conditions' => $addr_conditions));
            //$zip_to_search = $addr_state['Zip']['zip_code'];

            $conditions[] = array('Listing.State' => $state);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
var type;

if (postcode == true) {
    type = postcode;
} else {
    type = notAPostCode;
}

return type;
```

Comment: This isn't even close to what I'm looking for. Did you even read the question?